# How to use GET without authentication but the POST/UPDATE with authentication in tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose I have a single resource in tastypie:

```
class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Question.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

How do I allow anyone to get the questions without authentication but need authentication with post in one single resource class?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I allow anyone to get the questions without authentication but need authentication with post in one single resource class?

A good approach is to implement a subclass of BasicAuthentication:

```
class CustomAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
   def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
      if request.method == 'GET':
          return True
      return BasicAuthentication.is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
```

Then use your new class as the `authentication` option:

```
class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Question.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        authentication = CustomAuthentication()
```

Some more information can be found in the [tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#basicauthentication).

An alternate approach is to override the `is_authenticated` method in your resource (which by default calls the Authentication instance in Meta):

```
class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    (...)
    def is_authenticated(self, request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        return ModelResource.is_authenticated(request)
```

Note that while this approach is [viable and documented](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=authentication#is-authenticated) it is a specific implementation for one particular resource. If your application has multiple resources that require the same authentication semantics, use subclassing to make it reusable.